# AWSELB Cookie access from Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cors

I having problems to access the "Set-Cookie" header where AWSELB id is stored in order to set it for the subsequent requests.

I thought it was a problem with CORS configuration so i tried:

```
cors.headers = [
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, authorization, accept, content-type, x-requested-with, X-Auth-Token, Set-Cookie, set-cookie',
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Set-Cookie, set-cookie'
]
cors.allow.origin.regex = '.*'
cors.expose.headers = 'Set-Cookie, set-cookie'
```

In the server side.

I can see all those CORS headers in the response, still when i try to getAllResponseHeaders from client side i cannot see "Set-Cookie" neither i can get specific header by name.

I am missing something?

I've check this in both Chrome and Firefox

EDIT1: This is my JS side

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(dataMock),
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "text",
            success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie')) {
                    document.cookie = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: `contentType: "text",` is wrong— it isn't a MIME type and you aren't sending plain text. It should be: `contentType: "applicatication/json"`.

Comment: Thank you for the point but i've set "text" on purpose. I think that does not have relation with the problem.

Comment: It isn't related to the problem, which is why it is a comment. It is still utterly wrong though. (And I made a typo in my previous comment, it should be `application/json`)

Comment: It's utterly wrong according to the standards.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are explicitly excluded from [`getResponseHeader`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getresponseheader()-method) and [`getAllResponseHeaders`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders()-method):

> client . getAllResponseHeaders()
>
> Returns all headers from the response, with the exception of those whose field name is Set-Cookie or Set-Cookie2.
>
> client . getAllResponseHeaders()
>
> Returns all headers from the response, with the exception of those whose field name is Set-Cookie or Set-Cookie2.

If you want to access them directly from JS then you must change the server so that it duplicates the information in them elsewhere in the response.

Comment: I just want make work the Sticky Session AWS ELB ... but this cookie is created automatically by this AWS service, i do not have control to make such that process